# Aura mods are obtained as reward or by drop chance?

Tags: warframe

As far as I understand, auras are available only in alert missions.

But are they supposed to appear also as a pickup object in the middle of the mission, or only obtained as a promised reward after finishing the mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auras can only be obtained from alert missions, when the alert says you will get one. It is given at the end of the mission upon completion. They can not be obtained from any other place, whether mod drop or mission completion.

http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Aura

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I said. Now the question is, it is obtained by drop chance (picking it up as any mod could be dropped) during the mission, or only as a reward after accomplishing it?

Comment: I changed my answer so it fits better with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Auras that show up for alert mission are given as an additional reward when you complete the related mission.

This is a guaranteed reward, provided you succeed in doing the mission.